# Telling GNU readline to autoquote/autoescape file names like bash does

Tags: c, readline, libreadline

I'm adding `readline` support for a program with an interactive shell.

I've found some great examples online [like this one](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tab-completion-in-gnu-readline) but I'm having trouble telling `readline` to automatically expand file names with `\␣` when the file name has a whitespace.

The blog post mentioned above explains how to do that with custom completion. However I have a command of the type `load filename`, so for the second argument I'm letting `readline` do the default behaviour which is to complete file names by setting `rl_attempted_completion_over` to 0.

I'm also reading [the api documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/rlman_2.html#SEC36) and there are several functions and variables related to that topic, however I'm a little bit overwhelmed with that documentation, that's too much information to take it at once.

So simple example:

```
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main(void)
{
    rl_filename_quoting_desired = 1;
    rl_filename_quote_characters = " \t\n\"\\'`@$><=;|&{(";
    rl_filename_completion_desired = 1;
    rl_filename_quoting_desired = 1;
    // rl_completer_quote_characters = "\"";  see explanation below

    char *buffer = readline("> ");
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

So, if I run this

```
> fi<TAB>
file with spaces.txt  firefox_shaoran/
> fil<TAB>
> file with spaces.txt
```

But I want `readline` to exapnd like bash does, that means after `> file<TAB>` I want to get `file\ with\ spaces.txt`.

I've been playing around with the different variables provided by `readline`, but I cannot get the same result. In the documentation of `rl_basic_word_break_characters` it says that bash uses `" \t\n\"\\'@$><=;|&{("`. I tried setting `rl_filename_completion_desired` and 
`rl_filename_quoting_desired` to 1, but it doesn't work either.

What should I do in the simple example so that `readline` expands file names as bash does?

// edit:

After reading a little bit of the bash source code, I came across the `bashline.c` file and found a place where `rl_filename_quote_characters` and `rl_completer_quote_characters` are set. In my example I commented that line because without it, the behaviour didn't change. However if I uncomment the line, `readline` quotes file names with empty spaces, which is great. What I haven't found so far in the documentation is how to escape the completion instead of quoting it.

I also tried `rl_completer_quote_characters = "\"";`

Comment: please add your attempted code into the actual main function there...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've updated my code and I found a way that `readline` automatically quotes file names with spaces. I'd like to know how to escape the file names instead of quoting them.